# Graph Struct in C

Tags: c, struct, graph

I am using a dynamic 2D array.

I want to implement a graph in a struct so I can just call like:

```
initialize(&costs);
initialize(&pred);
```

The graph structure is `G = [ COSTS[1:n,1:n], pred[1:n, 1:n], n]` where  `n` is the number of vertices.

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int **matrix = NULL;
    int n = 0;
    int i, j;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    matrix = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    // matrix is now an array of pointers to integers, which can be used as an array of integer arrays, hence a 2d matrix

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // create an array for each ith element of matrix;
        matrix[i] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 0; //initialize values
        }
    }
}
```

Can you suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a struct containing two matrices? You may as well put `n` in it as well, so it would be something like:

```
typedef struct {
    int n;
    int **cost;
    int **pred;
} graph;
```

Use the initialisation code you've written on each of the matrices in turn. Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` if this is C.

Comment: oh okay :) then i can make a function for initializing matrices. thanks :)